# Why does systemd-resolved stop resolving with Ubuntu 18.04.6?

Tags: dns

Host lulu has rebooted. It is the DNS server (`lulu`, bind9). From another machine (`ppr01`), I do the following. It seems I have to do this every time the DNS server, `lulu`, restarts. I could do away with `sytemd-resolved` and return to the traditional use of `/etc/resolv.conf` but I'd like to give this new implementation a chance.

```
ppr01# host lulu
Host lulu not found: 2(SERVFAIL)

ppr01# systemctl restart systemd-resolved

ppr01# host lulu
lulu.vvo.win has address 192.168.1.205
```

Why do I need to `restart systemd-resolved` for clients every time the DNS server restarts?

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` on `ppr01` as you bounce `lulu` to get some hints. Look for the way `lulu` announces itself. Who is the DNS provider? `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: I don't see `lulu`, the DNS server, annoucing itself from the client `ppr01` with `journalctl  --follow`. I am able to reproduce this consistently though. After I simulate DNS server failure with `systemctl stop named` I cannot get the client to resolve records in the local domain `vvo.win` until I do `systemctl restart systemd-resolved` This doesn't bode well for a resilient system!

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.